# How to find anchor inner item in recyclerView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm stuck in one small issue, where i need to find anchor item from recyclerView center visible item

Please check below image for reference
[image]

below code i'm using to find center item from recyclerView

```
class CenterItemFinder(
  private val context: Context,
  private val layoutManager: LinearLayoutManager,
  private val callback: CenterItemCallback,
  private val controlState: Int
) : OnScrollListener() {
  override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
    if (controlState == ALL_STATES || newState == controlState) {
      val firstVisible = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
      val lastVisible = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()
      val itemsCount = lastVisible - firstVisible + 1
      val screenCenter = context.resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels / 2
      var minCenterOffset = Int.MAX_VALUE
      var middleItemIndex = 0
      for (index in 0 until itemsCount) {
        val listItem = layoutManager.getChildAt(index) ?: return
        val leftOffset = listItem.left
        val rightOffset = listItem.right
        val centerOffset =
          Math.abs(leftOffset - screenCenter) + Math.abs(rightOffset - screenCenter)
        if (minCenterOffset > centerOffset) {
          minCenterOffset = centerOffset
          middleItemIndex = index + firstVisible
        }
      }
      callback.scrollFinished(middleItemIndex)
    }
  }

  interface CenterItemCallback {
    fun scrollFinished(middleElement: Int)
  }

  companion object {
    const val ALL_STATES = 10
  }
}
```

I want to find inner anchor item in recyclerView but not able to find exact center visible inner item in recyclerView

i'm able to find the center visible item of recyclerView but not able to find anchor inner item

Here is the reference video for the same

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OIPq-YOFhch6xFpSZGEFZTDHhDisicDg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you please clarify some definitions `center visible item of recyclerView` and `center visible inner item`. can you please explain more ?

Comment: @HussienFahmy when user scroll the recyclerview i want  to change the color of this https://prnt.sc/25wvxva item which was in the center of anchor date button

Comment: This is not clear enough . What do u mean by anchor item ? all i see is a tool tip view .  Could you please edit your question with a better clarification of these . what Anchor? when you say center do you mean Center of screen or a fully visible item ? Also are you using any SnapHelper for this arrangement or not ?

Comment: @ADM i'm not using `SnapHelper` i want to change the, `when you say center do you mean Center of screen or a fully visible item ?` i mean center in tooltip view

Comment: @ADM added video for reference

Comment: i saw the video. I can not answer at the moment its too much but you do need a `SnapHelper` for this behavior. you have create a custom one probably quite similar to `PagerSnapHelper` but when calculating distance you need to take the inner items width in consideration. Also you need provide ClipPadding to recycler view dynamically (which you might already have )to handle the first and last item Snapping .

Comment: I see you have 3 items in each RV row/item; the most left & right items have numbers; and the middle item seems a dummy; Do you mean by `not able to find anchor inner item` that the anchor is the of those numbered items that points to the date button? I already see that you can change its color in the video

Comment: Yes @Zain i want find anchor items of that numbered  items and want change its color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The idea is that the anchor view is that closer to the center:**

First get the x position of the centered item on the screen (i.e. left edge), add the item width to get the right edge; then compare that to center point of the screen to know which edge is closer to the center.

But first, we need to get the `ViewHolder` instance associated to that centered item to get these positions & access the underlying views.

You already got the position of the centered item (`middleItemIndex`) in the `RecyclerView` within the `onScrollStateChanged()` callback. Then to get the associated `ViewHolder` instance for this position:

```
val holder =
    recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(middleItemIndex) as MyViewHolder // Cast that to your ViewHolder class

// Get the centered item position on the screen
val point = IntArray(2)
holder.itemView.getLocationOnScreen(point) // or getLocationInWindow(point)

val leftEdge = point[0]
val rightEdge = leftEdge + holder.itemView.width
val screenCenter = resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels / 2

val leftOffset = Math.abs(leftEdge - screenCenter)
val rightOffset = Math.abs(rightEdge - screenCenter)


// And eventually get the anchor view:
val anchorView = if (leftOffset > rightOffset) {
    // The right view is the anchor
    holder.itemView.findViewById<...>(R.id.rightItemId) // adjust rightItemId to your most right view id in the RV item

} else {
    // The left view is the anchor 
    holder.itemView.findViewById<...>(R.id.leftItemId) // adjust leftItemId to your most left view id in the RV item
}
```

### UPDATE

> using this condition if (leftOffset > rightOffset) { i'm able to
> detect first and last block from recyclerview, the issue is that i'm
> not able to detect the center block item (the item which have ...)

You can divide the centered item into 3 equal parts, where there will be two edges to compare to the screen center position:

```
// Get the centered item x,y position on the screen
val point = IntArray(2)
holder.itemView.getLocationOnScreen(point) // or getLocationInWindow(point)

val itemWidth = holder.itemView.width

// Divide the width into 3 equal parts (two margins)
val leftMargin = point[0] + itemWidth / 3
val rightMargin = point[0] + itemWidth * 2 / 3

val anchorView =
    when {
        screenCenter > rightMargin -> {
            // The anchor is the right item
            holder.itemView.findViewById<..>(R.id.rightItemId) // adjust rightItemId to the most right view id in the RV item
        }
        screenCenter > leftMargin -> {
            // The anchor is the middle item
            holder.itemView.findViewById<..>(R.id.middleItemId) // adjust rightItemId to the middle view id in the RV item
        }
        else -> {
            // The anchor is the left item
            holder.itemView.findViewById<..>(R.id.leftItemId) // adjust rightItemId to the most left view id in the RV item

        }
    }
```

Comment: I have found one issue it i'm not able to skip center block inside it can you please help me on that

Comment: can you help to find out center item as well

Comment: `i'm not able to skip center block inside it` Can you clarify more this I didn't get you well

Comment: `help to find out center item` >> if you mean the center RV item, this is `holder.itemView`; and if you mean the centered item within the row item, this is `holder.itemView.findViewById<..>(R.id.myItemID)`

Comment: using this condition `if (leftOffset > rightOffset) {` i'm able to detect first and last block from recyclerview, the issue is that i'm not able to detect the center block item `(the item which have ...)`

Comment: Gotcha, Is the centered item can be an anchor as well? I couldn't get that from the video as the date doesn't point to it. How do you want make it an anchor; i.e. which conditions you want any of the three items to be considered the anchor?

Comment: `Is the centered item can be an anchor as well?` Yes,  there is no specific condition what i want is that when the anchor date is at first and and last position i want to change the color and when anchor item is center block then i want to set different color

Comment: @Goku Thanks for clarifying that, just updated the answer, hopefully it works

Comment: Thank you very much buddy really appreciate your help